# How to select and play different audio files with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I am currently using `AVAudioPlayer` to play an MP3 file when the method is triggered. 
This works well however I would now like to add in the ability to select which audio file is played when the method is triggered from a list, this is not going so well.

I have created a `UISegmentedControl` and attempted to change the `AVAudioPlayer` method to reflect what has been selected however I am now receiving the following error when the app is launched:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

From what I understand, I am recieving the above error because when the `AVAudioPlayer` is attempting to `initWithContentsOfUrl:`, the string being referenced does not contain any data yet, I thought it may have got this from the default segment in the `UISegmentedController`, however this is not the case.

I have searched for a solution for this but could not find anything which matched what i was attempting to achieve, the closest I could find was to initiate a new session of `AVAudioPlayer` for every audio file I wanted to play however this seemed very long winded and ultimatly may still not work.

Below is my code so far, if you could suggest how I could make this work, I would appreciate it.

for the `UISegmentedController`:

```
- (void) selectTone:(id)sender
{
    if (self.alarmToneType == 0) {
        self.filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"alarm" ofType: @"mp3"];
        NSLog(@"Tone Selected 0 %@", [HRASettingsViewController alarmToneDescription:(int) self.alarmToneType]);
    }

    if (self.alarmToneType == 1) {
        self.filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"redalert" ofType: @"mp3"];
        NSLog(@"Tone Selected 1 %@", [HRASettingsViewController alarmToneDescription:(int) self.alarmToneType]);
    }
    if (self.alarmToneType == 2) {
        self.filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"greenalaert" ofType: @"mp3"];
        NSLog(@"Tone Selected 2 %@", [HRASettingsViewController alarmToneDescription:(int) self.alarmToneType]);
    }

}
```

I have created the string as a @property above but didn't think you would need that.

for the `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
- (void) setupAppAudio {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SOUNDS

    // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Use this code instead to allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &sessionError];

    if (sessionError) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession ERROR %@", sessionError);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession SUCCESSFUL");
    }

    // Tell other music to be quiet when we are talking!
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;

    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck,
                             sizeof (doSetProperty),
                             &doSetProperty);

    // Registers the audio route change listener callback function
    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
                                     audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
                                     (__bridge void *)(self));

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

    // setup
    //NSString *filePath;
    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer;

    newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath] error: nil];
    self.beepPlayer = newPlayer;

    // "Preparing to play" attaches to the audio hardware and ensures that playback
    //      starts quickly when the user taps Play
    [self.beepPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.beepPlayer setVolume: 1.0];
    [self.beepPlayer setDelegate: self];



}
```

Comment: Check if `self.filePath` is set before playing. You can set it also to first choice of the segmented control by default.

Comment: Ok thank you, how would i go about doing that? I have already set the segmented controllers default to be the correct MP3 file however that obviously is not being loaded into the string and i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Something i have tried which did get rid of the message was in 'viewDidLoad' i ran 'self.filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"alarm" ofType: @"mp3"];' which solved the error problem however when selecting different alarm types from the 'UISegmentedController' the type did not change.

Comment: There is no "play or prepare to play" called when you change the filePath.